# Firefox Cannot Display Chinese

Tags: 14.04, firefox, language-support

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I open a Chines web page, for example, [this](http://www.bookbao.com/view/201501/17/id_XMzg3MTA5.html) in Firefox, I got all crazy symbols. How to ask Firefox to display Chinese correctly, please? Could anyone provide a step by step guide, please? Thank you!

Comment: You need to add an example url or two to your question.

Comment: For example, http://www.bookbao.com/view/201501/17/id_XMzg3MTA5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular web page is the problem. If you check the source (Ctrl+U), the only character set (charset) encoding specified is GB2312. Firefox won't detect it automatically.

Nowadays, most web sites intended for international viewing should use Unicode (UTF-8) for compatibility. For example, if you check:
[*http://www.xinhuanet.com/*](http://www.xinhuanet.com/)
you should see normal Chinese text. If you check the source (Ctrl+U), near the top of the page you will see:
charset=utf-8

In Firefox, you can select a different character encoding in the View menu. You would have to check those listed as Chinese to see if the text is legible.

Comment: Yup. I think I have all the language support necessary installed, played with encoding, and yet that page is still gibberish

Comment: In the Firefox text encoding list, do you have Chinese Simplified? And when you select it, do you see Kanji that make no sense, or some other gibberish? You might want to add a screenshot of what you are seeing to your question.

Comment: Thank you. By selecting simplified Chinese coding, I can read the page.